# (-216:No CUDA support) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function 'throw_no_cuda'

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I build opencv from source and I would like to use in on the GPU, so I did all the flags, but still I have this issue if I want to put an image on the GPU. Does anyone have an idea? Here is how the configuration looks like in the end [here](https://pastebin.com/pWHFkigf). I already struggle for hours with that. I think the configuration is right but maybe some path isn't?

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-v7sdauef/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:106: error: (-216:No CUDA support) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function 'throw_no_cuda'
```

Comment: According to your build log, you're compiling OpenCV 4.5.2. This error message says it's from OpenCV 4.4.0... You're loading something else than what you built.

Comment: you compiled OpenCV 4.5.2, but the error is about OpenCV 4.4.0. Copy the result of your build into your site_packages

Comment: ah makes sense. what would be the name of the folder? and how would I set that this is the build that should be run when I work with opencv?